# Unity: Difference between GetPixels32() & GetPixels32(colors)

Tags: unity-game-engine, texture2d

I am making a mobile application using Unity where I open the camera and get data from it using `WebcamTexture`.

The data which I get from the camera is `Color32[]`.

I stored the data in the memory and then read it from memory:

```
// Address the variable (data) to a memory location
data = new Color32[width * height];
gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);

// this didn't work
data = webcamTexture.GetPixels32();

// this worked fine
webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data);

// read data from memory using this
gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
```

When I used `webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data);` I was able to see the image of the camera, while when I used `data = webcamTexture.GetPixels32();` I am getting a black screen from the camera.

**My Questions:**

**1. Is there a difference between the two functions?**

**2. What I should do if I want to get `Color32[]` from `Texture2D`?
        (`Texture2D` has 2 functions to get `Color32[]`: `GetPixels32()` and
        `GetRawTextureData<Color32>().ToArray()`, both giving me a black
        screen)**

Comment: Could you show your complete code please? Did you checkout [`WebCamTexture.GetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixels32.html)? Is your webCam started (`webcamTexture.Play();`)?

Comment: webcamTexture has started and `webcamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame` is true. I am using the same code and just switching between these 2 methods to get `Color32[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the title

> Difference between GetPixels32() & GetPixels32(colors)

If you look into the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.GetPixels32.html) you will see that the method signature is

```c#
public Color32[] GetPixels32(Color32[] colors = null);
```

so `colors` is an [optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments).

So on a very high level perspective: **There is no difference, both are the same method.**

---

**However**, this parameter wouldn't exist, if the method wouldn't behave different with or without it.

If you read on

> You can optionally pass in an array of `Color32`s to use in colors to avoid allocating new memory each frame, which is faster when you are continuously reading data from the camera. The array needs to be initialized to a length matching width * height of the texture. **If you don't pass an array, `GetPixels32` will allocate one for you and return it**.

you see that the difference in passing in an array or not is that if you don't do it, it **allocates a new array** for every time you call it. This is of course a lot more expensive if you are using this every frame. But letting aside this performance impact it also means that this way you get a new array reference every time.

---

So this said now looking again into your code you are doing

```c#
data = new Color32[width * height];
gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

so if you are filling this array it is still the same array object

```c#
webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data);
var ptr = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

so this works since you are filling the same array reference that is pinned in the `gcHandle`.

---

On the other side this does not work

```c#
data = webcamTexture.GetPixels32();
var ptr = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

since here you create a **new array reference**. On this one you didn't call

```c#
gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

on and thus, when you reach

```c#
gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject()
```

this `gcHandle` still references to the previous `Color32[]` which was referenced by `data` the moment you did the `Alloc` call. That is still an empty array you did never write to.

---

For `Texture2D` it should be [`GetPixels32()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html) but you would probably want to first get that array before getting the pointer to it:

```c#
var data = texture2D.GetPixels32();
var gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var ptr = gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
```

Comment: Which second one? You said `When I used webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data); I was able to see the image of the camera` so shouldn't this already be the answer then?

Comment: @BilalSehwail again: You said `When I used webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data); I was able to see the image of the camera` wouldn't this answer the second question as well? It it works using the `webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data);` then this is how you get your pixels, right? Before it just didn't work because as said you were using `data = webcamTexture.GetPixels32();` but then where later reading from an empty array

Comment: So why did you say `When I used webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data); I was able to see the image of the camera` then?